# Yii Booster datepicker not working correctly

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions

I have an issue which related to Yii booster datepicker.

scenario:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm',array(
'id'=>'expend-form',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
'type'=>'horizontal',   )); ?>

<p class="help-block">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<?php // echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'fecha',array('class'=>'span5')); 
    echo $form->datepickerRow($model, 'fecha',
            array('prepend'=>'<i class="icon-calendar"></i>' 
                    , 'options'=>array( 'format' => 'dd/mm/yyyy', 
                                        'weekStart'=> 1,
                                        'showButtonPanel' => true,
                                        'showAnim'=>'fold',)
            )
        );

?>
```

Problem is:

options:

```
'showButtonPanel' => true,
'showAnim'=>'fold',
```

not working.

and the CSS have something wrong (check the screenshot)

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Nathanphan, the reason your CSS has something wrong is because the Yii css files are overriding the YiiBooster CSS. Open your `main.php` layout file under /protected/views/layouts and delete the following line.  **You may want to delete all of the CSS links.**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/screen.css" media="screen, projection" />
```

You should find that your YiiBooster widgets appear properly now; however some of the Yii widgets on your site may now look incorrect.  You can convert your Yii widgets to equivalent YiiBooster widgets and then everything should be fine.

I've not found a way to run the Yii blueprint CSS and YiiBooster at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

@Nathanphan, you're trying to use a option from [zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker](http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/jquery.html#datepicker) in a `TbDatePicker`, which is based on [Bootstrap Datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/).
If you have a need to use these options (`showButtonPanel` and `showAnim`), change your code to use the `CJuiDatePicker` widget.

Comment: Can anyone help out with this?

Answer (score 0):

in main.css find and replace

`thead th {background:e5eCf9;}`

to

`thead th {background:#ffffff;}`

and

`.box {padding:1.5em;margin-bottom:1.5em;background:#e5eCf9;}`

to

`.box {padding:1.5em;margin-bottom:1.5em;background:#ffffff;}`