# YiiBooster CSS apparently not loading

Tags: yii

I have installed YiiBooster and am using the latest Yii v1.1.13. My `main.php` file contains the following configuration:

```
'preload'=>array('log','bootstrap'),
// application components
  'components'=>array(
    'bootstrap'=>array(
      'class'=>'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
      'responsiveCss'=>true,
    ),
    'user'=>array(
      'class'=>'RWebUser',
      // enable cookie-based authentication
      'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
      'loginUrl'=> array('/user/login'),
    ), 
...
```

However, after doing this none, of the YiiBooster widgets are displaying properly. As a new user I am not able to post images; however, my `datepickerRow()` widget looks just like the one in this post: [Yii Booster datepicker not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081365/yii-booster-datepicker-not-working-correctly).  The 'look' of the widget is not normal.

I have a number of other problems with other widgets. The bigger problem is the TbExtendedGridView that is not showing any of the View/Edit/Delete icons.  Actually none of my 'prepend' icons are working on the forms either.  Any ideas?

As requested - here is an example of a widget not working correctly.  None of the little icons for view/edit/delete are shown.  Also the row striping is not working, and the column title bar is a strange color.

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider, 
    'type'=>'striped',
    'columns'=>array(
        'Registration',
        'WONumber',
        'InspectionType',
        'LogEntryDate',
        ),

));
```

I am also having trouble with a textfieldRow() control.  So I don't believe this is a problem with widgets, I think it is something to do with the way I have YiiBooster configured.

---

**UPDATE - Still Not Working**

I have found that the file in conflict with the CSS is the /var/www/intranet/css/screen.css file.  When I remove this file from my main.php layout file, the CSS from YiiBooster works properly.  The problem is that the rest of the page looks terrible.

So, I'm still researching why I can't run blueprint CSS and YiiBooster at the same time.  Any help would be appreciated.

---

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

I found that other people were having trouble running the stock Yii blueprint CSS setup, so I switched completely over to YiiBooster and have not had any problems.  I removed the CSS links in my main.php layout file.  After converting all of the Yii widgets to YiiBooster widgets, everything works great.

Comment: That's how mine is set up. Is it listed in the extensions directory correctly?

Comment: @Jonnny, I'm not sure what you mean by 'listed' correctly.  The bootstrap folder is in the extensions folder and the widgets are loading but not operating correctly.

Comment: I was seeing if it was in the right directory structure. Do you have some example code of the widget failing?

Comment: From where have you downloaded the bootstrap ??

Comment: HI @Ninad, I downloaded the extension from [link](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following to your grid as an element of the columns array:

```
array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 50px'),
    ),
```

Comment: Thanks @jmarkmurphy, that code helped - I was able to add a column to the grid; however the column is blank.  None of the characters from font-awesome.html are showing up.

Comment: I figured out why the characters from font-awesome.html were not working.  I had to enable it in my main.php config file by adding `'fontAwesomeCss'=>true` to the bootstrap array in the components array.